# Touch Controls Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to use touch controls to move my character on a device such as an iPhone. So far I have had limited success. This code works but only with one of the buttons. I have both a left and right button and the left button worked until I added the right button. Now only the right button works. Any help would be appreciated.

```
foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
    {

        if(leftButton.guiTexture.HitTest(touch.position) && touch.phase != TouchPhase.Ended)
            {
                move = -1;
                anim.SetFloat ("Speed", Mathf.Abs (move));

            }
        else if(rightButton.guiTexture.HitTest(touch.position) && touch.phase != TouchPhase.Ended)
            {
                move = 1;
                anim.SetFloat ("Speed", Mathf.Abs (move));
            }
        else if((leftButton.guiTexture.HitTest(touch.position) && touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended) && 
                (rightButton.guiTexture.HitTest(touch.position) && touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended))
            {
                move = 0;
            }

    }
```

Comment: how are you checking if the buttons are working? You're setting the animation parameter `Speed` in both cases to `1`

Answer (score 0):

An much easier alternative method for clicking would be

```
if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    //Your stuff here
}
```

remember to change input for clickable object (which i think is touch)

Comment: I believe so but you would probably have to create a  clickable object first rather than gui. So looking back on it, it doesnt seem to be as feasible sorry. If someone wants to correct me feel free. Try posting to unity answers if you do not get an answer

Comment: You can make this work with GUI if you want to be really simple with it: that is, get mouse position (it's in screen coordinates), then simply test if it's inside the rectangle of the GUI object based on its position and size.

Answer (score 0):

First, do a sanity check and verify that the left and right buttons are setup correctly on your component.

I'm not currently on a computer with unity to test everything, but there is a lot of redundancy here, we can clean it up to make debugging the problem easier. Another red flag is I don't see move being set to 0 before the input check, so I'll add that. Try this code and see if you are still seeing the problem, and perhaps you will be able to better debug with monodevelop what is happening.

```
move = 0;
bool isLeftPressed = false;
bool isRightPressed = false;

foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
{
    // Only process touches that aren't in the ended phase
    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        return;

    if (leftButton.guiTexture.HitTest(touch.position))
        isLeftPressed = true;

    if (rightButton.guiTexture.HitTest(touch.position))
        isRightPressed = true;
}

if (isLeftPressed && isRightPressed)
{
    // Do nothing when both are pressed (move already set to 0)
}
else if (isLeftPressed)
{
    move = -1;
}
else if (isRightPressed)
{
    move = 1;
}

anim.SetFloat ("Speed", Mathf.Abs (move));
```

I made a few assumptions about what you were trying to do with the check if both left and right are pressed. Rather than setting the move value in the foreach loop, we just set flags so that after processing each touch we can see which buttons are being pressed (If finger 0 is touching one, and finger 1 is touching the other, I assume that means you want there to be no movement?)